# 25 cm of vacuum correspond to what pressure?

Tags: pressure, units, si-units

I the following (american) test

> Vacuum testing consists of placing samples from the packiging operation into a jar filled with water. A lid is placed over the samples to fully immerse them in the water. A container lid is applied to create a seal effective enough to create approximately **25 cm of vacuum**. The vacuum pump is set, and the samples are tested for approximately 1 minute...

Is 25 cm of vacuum equal to 333 or -667 mbar (or are the +- opposite)?

or

does it just mean that there has to be 25 cm distance from the water front to the container lid **__**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it could represent the pressure of that much water, my first thought is that it is a pressure difference equal to 25 cm of Hg, or 250mmHg.  25cm of water would be a quite weak vacuum.

Since it's a vacuum, the internal pressure would be ambient minus that amount.
$P_{abs} = 1013mbar + (-333mbar) = 680mbar$

Comment: Which bits?  1atm ~ 1013mbar.  250mmHg ~ 333mbar.  Or are you saying the equation is incorrect?

Comment: My mistake - sorry

Comment: Do you know why the packaging is being vacuum tested at all?  680mbar is not considered a strong vacuum.  It would be found not too far above 10,000 feet altitude.

Comment: It's made to test a seal between alu-alu.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that 25 cm of vacuum refers to a vacuum which is at 25 cmHg of pressure.

I do think going down to 25 cmHg would mean ~33,330 Pa; that's within the range of a [low vacuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum#Measurement).